# Why is my model giving different results with the same parameters?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, classification, grid-search

I am tuning my model with these parameters:

```
param_grid = {
'unit_1': 128, 
'unit_2': 64,
'lr': 3e-4, 
'activ': 'relu',
'epochs': 400, 
'batch_size': 8}
```

Which is to say, I already know the parameters I'll be using, but I run these through the search function anyway, like so:

```
kgs = KerasGridSearch(build_classifier_model, param_grid,
                    monitor='val_loss', greater_is_better=False)

kgs.search({'text': x_train_text, 'vector': x_train_vector}, y_train,
               sample_weight=y_train_weight,
               batch_size=param_grid['batch_size'],
               validation_data = ({'text': x_val_text, 'vector': x_val_vector},
                                  y_val,y_val_weight),
               callbacks=[es])
```

I then evaluate the model that results from this search and get some results:

- Loss: 1.5514
- Accuracy: 0.6601
- Weighted accuracy: 0.6879

However, when I try to train a new model using the same parameters, this time with the fit() function, I get very different results.

```
history = classifier_model.fit({'text': x_train_text, 'vector': x_train_vector},
                               y_train,
                               sample_weight=y_train_weight,
                               steps_per_epoch=len(x_train_text) // best_params['batch_size'],
                               validation_data=({'text': x_val_text,
                                                 'vector': x_val_vector},
                                                y_val,y_val_weight),
                               batch_size = best_params['batch_size'],
                               epochs=best_params['epochs']+10,
                               callbacks=[es])
```

- Loss: 1.0226
- Accuracy: 0.4915
- Weighted accuracy: 0.5092

I have run the notebook repeatedly and the same thing happens. It is not making sense to me. I hope it isn't something obvious I'm missing. Please let me know if there is more information I can include to help solve this issue.

Comment: Have you heard of random weight initialization?

Comment: I have learned that neural networks are initialized with random weights. Is that what you mean? The search function is consistently performing in the 65% accuracy range while the fit function consistently performs around 50%. Could these functions be initializing the weights differently?

Comment: Yes each time you instance a model, its weights are randomly initialized. It  is not a function problem, even if you train the same model two times, you will get two sets of randomly initialized weights.

Comment: That would not explain why the model is consistently 15% more accurate when trained with the search function. Maybe I did not explain this clearly in the original question.